# ASP MVC with jQuery, how to approach inline editor design?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to both ASP.NET MVC and jQuery and in process of designing my first inline (in-place) editor for a html table. In short - when user clicks on a e.g "Unit price" `td`, jQuery clones a hidden `ajax.beginform` to replace the `td`  and makes it visible. Form includes pre-set MVC helpers like `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.UnitPrice)`, `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` etc. User can POST the form and receive `tr` back from the controller. This works nicely.

Now, say I want to extend same functionality to another `td`, for example "Quantity". I have few options:

1. Add second hidden form to the page with proper helpers, e.g `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Quantity)` and show it to the user instead. This means I will end up with a hidden form per editable field (could be around 10 in total).
2. Continue with single form, but process the cloned DOM object with jQuery before presenting it and replace UnitPrice with Quantity everywhere where required, manually adjust all validation properties (`-data-val`) etc etc.
3. When user clicks on a `td`, use jQuery to make a request to a controller, which would return an appropriate PartialView.

Question - which of these options is most feasible? Are there any better alternatives? First option is definitely not DRY, but seems most maintainable, however I have no idea about how costly it is to keep several unused forms in the DOM.

Comment: I think your best bet in this case is option 3. You will have only one form to manage. Take that form with relevant information based on the cell you clicked and replace the td contents with that input field.

Comment: But then I make a request to controller, just to receive a template. Seems like an overkill, no?

Comment: If you were to go about this any other way than inline editing, you would be posting a reqeust to the server for an edit form. I understand your point but I see this solution as being far more manageable than having a huge view with multiple forms showing and hiding input fields.
The client comes back and says they want another whole field in your table inline editable.. which would be more manageable?

Comment: I suspect you probably want something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9madrh7g/2/) - a popup form to edit all fields in a row. The edit form can be part of the initial view (hidden) and its just populated with the values of the selected row

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the input.
I opted for a 4th solution where I keep a single hidden form with all the editable fields in the view. Depending on the clicked `td`, I remove all unnecessary fields\elements with jQuery and keep only the relevant one between the form tags before presenting the form to the user.